# How does this opamp circuit work?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an old PCB that I need repair, but the PCB is so old that I would prefer to make a new one.

After I studied its circuit and made a new PCB, I found the new PCB doesn't work. The output from opamp is different on the new PCB.

What kind of circuit is this?

Old PCB V1=2.93, V2=3, and Vo=6.22

New PCB V1=2.90, V2=2.93, and Vo=2.72

[image]

EDIT:

Here's the full schematic:

[image]

Comment: a capacitor in feedback always constitutes an integrating, so with your *constant voltage input*, you will **not** get a constant output here, and your description makes no sense. You might want to read up on op-amp integrators: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications

Comment: Make sure you have reverse-engineered the schematics correctly. I don't know what the device is and what it is supposed to do, but the capacitor between output and inverting input does not generally make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you sure R37 isn't supposed to be in series with V2? Something has to limit current for integration to work.

Comment: @Unimportant my guess is that there *is* another resistor "out of the picture" here, pretty much like R30 in series with V2, but OP considered that to not be part of the circuit.

Comment: Maybe R62 connects to pin 2 of the op-amp and not Vout

Comment: Since an LM324 is a quad op amp, this integrator is possibly inside of a loop with one or more of the other amplifiers.  Can you supply a full schematic?

Comment: Thank you. This is full schematic. It control heater by drive dc signal E2= 1 to 4.95Vdc. JS is connected to SCR module.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7oU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB7oU.png)